# Написал бота для скачивание видео с ютуба на aiogram, но он выдает ошибку

Tags: python, aiogram

Использую последнюю версию aiogram
код:

```
import asyncio
import os
import config
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, filters
from pytube import YouTube

async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.bot = bot

    @dp.message(filters.Command("download"))
    async def handle_download(message: types.Message):
        try:
            video_url = message.text.split()[1]
            save_path = "./"
            await message.answer('Видео в обработке')

            yt = YouTube(video_url)
            stream = yt.streams.filter(resolution='720p', progressive=True).first()
            video_file = stream.download(output_path=save_path)

            await message.answer(f"Видео '{yt.title}' успешно загружено!")

            with open(video_file, 'rb') as video:
                await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video)

            os.remove(video_file)

            await message.answer("Видео успешно отправлено и удалено с сервера.")
        except Exception as e:
            await message.answer(f"Произошла ошибка: {str(e)}")
    await dp.start_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
asyncio.run(main())
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\super\PycharmProjects\videobot\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 664, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\super\PycharmProjects\videobot\main.py", line 33, in main
    await dp.start_polling()
  File "C:\Users\super\PycharmProjects\videobot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 486, in start_polling
    raise ValueError("At least one bot instance is required to start polling")
ValueError: At least one bot instance is required to start polling
```

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/#simple-usage

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1569813

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1569813/valueerror-at-least-one-bot-instance-is-required-to-start-polling